# Matlab - read data with numeric and text columns

Tags: matlab, csv

Usually I load data using `load` or `csvread`. Now I need to load data with the following structure:

```
0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, some_text
0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, some_text2
...
```

In that `load` and `csvread` are both useless since they can only read numeric values. I found I could use `readtable` like this:

```
readtable('file.txt', 'Delimiter', ',', 'Format', '%f%f%f%f%s');
```

Now I have 2 problems:

1) `readtable` assumes that my file has header and I got one less line of data.

2) data stores in a Nx4 table and not in a Nx4 double Matrix

Any help to solve these 2 problems? Is there any function more useful in my case?

EDIT: In the end I only need to load the numeric values from the file (columns 1 : 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `readtable` with `textscan` in your code and you're almost there

Using your example *file.txt*

```
0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, some_text
0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, some_text2
```

Read with textscan

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
data = textscan(fid, '%f%f%f%f%s', 'Delimiter', ',');
fclose(fid);
```

Then you can collect the data from the first 4 columns

```
dataValues = [data{1:4}]
dataValues =
          0.1          0.2          0.3          0.4
          0.5          0.6          0.7          0.8
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work. Suppose you saved `./input.txt`:

```
1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, Hello world
6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9, How are you
```

To read this, use Matlab native line-by-line parse function `textscan`; here, '%s' for ([Mathwork documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)). 
It is wrapped in another cell. Extract the cell `hold_cell` which has only one element, and we have a `N` by 1 cell `x_in`. 
The rest is easy, if we recall a string is just an array of chars.

```
fid = fopen('./input.txt');
hold_cell = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');
x_in = hold_cell{1,1};
hold_size=size(x_in);
N=hold_size(1,1);

y_out =zeros(N,4);
for i=1:1:N
   hold_idx =strfind( x_in{i}, ',' );% those positions of comma
   y_out(i,1) =str2num( x_in{i,1}( 1 : hold_idx(1)-1 ) );% 1st number
   y_out(i,2) =str2num( x_in{i,1}( hold_idx(1)+1 : hold_idx(2)-1 ) );%2nd number
   y_out(i,3) =str2num( x_in{i,1}( hold_idx(2)+1 : hold_idx(3)-1 ) );%3rd number
   y_out(i,4) =str2num( x_in{i,1}( hold_idx(3)+1 : hold_idx(4)-1 ) );%4th number
end

disp(y_out);
```

output:

```
1.1000    2.2000    3.3000    4.4000
6.6000    7.7000    8.8000    9.9000
```

Comment: Not the downvoter but I don't know to use this. I need to load data from a file.